# How to change M2E local repository location?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

**My question is to do with Maven, M2E, Android and Eclipse.**

After some troubleshooting I managed to run the samples from the M2E website.

Everything is working **except for my Maven local repository location**

a) I have global variables M2 M2_HOME and such setup

b) My Maven set up is on E:\maven\repo\repository

c) My Maven conf\settings.xml contains the above location repository address

Maven's settings in Eclipse still reflect the User Home Directory .m2 as the local repository and it is uneditable. I have reloaded conf\settings.xml but to no avail.

One suggestion stated that I should change the Java build path settings, but the local repository variable in Eclipse is unmodifiable.

Another user posted a similar question and it was suggested that they change the Global Setting settings.xml file in Eclipse **but** the problem persists.

Here is my settings.xml setting for local repository

```
 <!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ~/.m2/repository
  <localRepository>E:/maven/repo/repository</localRepository>
```

I'd really like to find out how to get this working and it is really bugging me!

Appreciate all suggestions and help, Thank You

Comment: It seems like the part with your localRepository is still commented out. Could you post the complete file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i suspected, the configuration is commented out (`<!--` marks the beginning of a comment and `-->` the end of a comment in XML). Just move the line `<localRepository>E:/maven/repo/repository</localRepository>` behind the `-->`. Then the configuration should be active.

Comment: Thank you for your help dunni, I seemed to have overlooked that. This problem is resolved